# argmax() doesn't show timestamped index only index number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, argmax

I have a small dataframe like below:

[image: Dataframe]

Here is the code:

```
my_dates = [datetime(2016, 1, 1), datetime(2016, 1, 2), datetime(2016,1,3)]
dt_ind = pd.DatetimeIndex(my_dates)
data = [2,8,15]
cols = ['num']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,dt_ind,cols)
```

I am trying to find the date on which we have high value. So I used:

```
df['num'].argmax()
```

But instead of showing output as `2016-01-03`, I am getting `2`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

argmax returns index of the highest value, so in your case it's 2. Try max()

Comment: I actually want index but not as number but as an time stamp. Which in this case is 2016-01-03

Answer (score 0):

use

`df['num'].idxmax()`

instead of

`df['num'].argmax()`